# SQL - drop a column in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a  table`table1` like below from which i'm trying to drop a column.

#### table1

```
id name time    value
---------------------
1 john  11:00   324
2 NULL  12:00   645
3 NULL  13:00   324
4 jane  11:00   132
5 NULL  12:00   30
```

A temp table is created as the original table cannot be altered due to permissions. This case may be very simple to be done by selecting everything except id , but what I really need to do is get rid of one column when there are large number of cols.

```
create temp table table2 as(
select * from table1
) distribute on random;

alter table table2 drop column id;
```

this gives the error - `Drop behaviour (RESTRICT | CASCADE) needs to be specified when dropping a column or constraint`

How should the alter table statement be ?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message and [documentation say](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_alter_table.html), you need to specify either RESTRICT or CASCADE.  However, note that you can't drop a column from a true TEMPORARY table, so this only applies to normal tables.

```
ALTER TABLE <table> <action> [ORGANIZE ON {(<columns>) | NONE}]

Where <action> can be one of:

ADD COLUMN <col> <type> [<col_constraint>][,…] |
ADD <table_constraint> |
ALTER [COLUMN] <col> { SET DEFAULT <value> | DROP DEFAULT } |
DROP [COLUMN] column_name[,column_name…] {CASCADE | RESTRICT } |
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> {CASCADE | RESTRICT} |
MODIFY COLUMN (<col> VARCHAR(<maxsize>)) |
OWNER TO <user_name> |
RENAME [COLUMN] <col> TO <new_col_name> |
RENAME TO <new_table> |
SET PRIVILEGES TO <table>
```

Like this:

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table t1 (col1 bigint, col2 varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into t1 values (1,'One');
INSERT 0 1
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into t1 values (2,'Two');
INSERT 0 1
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into t1 values (3,'Three');
INSERT 0 1
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from t1;
 COL1 | COL2  
------+-------
    3 | Three
    1 | One
    2 | Two
(3 rows)

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table t1 drop column col2 restrict;
ALTER TABLE
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from t1;
 COL1 
------
    1
    2
    3
(3 rows)
```

As always, if you alter a table to drop or add a column, you should follow it up with a GROOM to clean up the versioned table:

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> groom table t1 versions;
NOTICE:  Groom will not purge records deleted by transactions that started after 2016-11-07 17:00:11.
NOTICE:  If this process is interrupted please either repeat GROOM VERSIONS or issue 'GENERATE STATISTICS ON "T1"'
NOTICE:  Groom processed 2 pages; purged 0 records; scan size unchanged; table size unchanged.
GROOM VERSIONS
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for dropping the column in Netezza

```
Alter table tablename drop columnname RESTRICT
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this: http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/netezza-l/netezza-issue-2467523
it seems that you can't DROP a column via ALTER TABLE, only a constraint.